# is freedos is better than windows?

Tags: operating-system

I would like to know if freedos is better than windows or not, and why, I mean in terms of operability and development capacity using one or the other.
And finally which onw would you use and why.
Thanks for your support,
John.

Answer (score 0):

This mainly would depend on what you're goal is for your operating system. If you're goal is to play some classic games or run legacy software, sure you would probably appreciate FreeDOS, as for anything else... Windows definitely wins out. In terms of development, Windows has a lot more active community and you will likely find more tools and resources on it. If you are looking for an similar open source OS, consider looking into Linux or even Kali Linux if you are familiar with that. The command line utility with those type of operating systems have a lot more flexibility and isn't as limited as FreeDOS.

So overall, Windows definitely wins out in terms of ease-of-use and development capacity.

Comment: In my opinion, yes.